# Simulate typewriter effect in textbox

Tags: c#, typing

I've searched a lot but didn't found anything , what I want to know is how I can type into a textbox slowly ... I mean for example , Typing letter by letter like if I was writing it ...

Comment: What? You want to programmatically slow down the user fingers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to simulate typing text into a UI in C# and want it to go more slowly to look closer to what a human would type.  If so then why not add artificial pauses in between sending key strokes?

```
void TypeText(string text) {
  foreach (var c in text) { 
    SendKeyStroke(c);
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
  }
}
```

Comment: This would keep the UI frozen until text is written though

Comment: @BlackBear yes if you are typing from within the application. I assumed the OP was sending key strokes to another application in which case this wouldn't cause any freezing of the destination app

Comment: May I ask how this should work exactly please , kinda new in C# 
and what's that SendKeyStroke .. cuz it gives error .
I prefer to understand the code instead Copying and paste

Comment: @user2822198 `SendkeyStroke` isn't a real function. Based on your question I assumed you already had a method for sending the key stroke to the application.  I used `SendKeyStroke` as a place holder for that

Comment: Still don't get it :( I'am planning to take one Button & One textbox .
Button launch the function and type the txt on Textbox

Comment: @user2822198 how are you planning on typing into the text box?